# Is it possible to add google docs in VF page?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I added a button on Account object. When I click on that button it will open a VF page.

When I click on the link it will take to the google drive.

My question is when I add link to the VF page and click on save 
is it possible to attach that link to the Notes and Attachment related list so that user can view that doc by opening that link ?

I know this is already there in salesforce standard functionality but i want to customize this.

Answer (score 2):

To show a GoogleDoc in the Notes and Attachments related list, you need to insert an Sobject `GoogleDoc` with `parentID` set to the parent object and `url` set to the URL of the document in Google's cloud.

[Full sobject documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_googledoc.htm?search_text=google)

[Enabling Google Docs for Salesforce doc](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=google_docs_activate.htm&language=en_US)

Note that once enabled, the Google Docs option appears on every Notes and Attachments related list.

Answer (score 0):

you can write a trigger on account object and create a note in it. Add the google docs link to content of note.